# Multiple labelled expressions on one line

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing

I have several tall, thin expressions - graphical diagrams - which I need to label as if they were equations. Given their shape, it would be mad to have them displayed one underneath the other. I really want to have them next to each other, and give them equation numbers displayed immediately underneath. How can I generate new equation numbers, and then typeset them wherever I please?

This is pseudocode for the sort of effect I want, where `\newlabel{blah}` is a fictional command which increments the equation count by 1, typesets `(n)` where `n` is the new equation number, and sets the label "blah" to refer to this new number.

```
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
\firstlongthinexpression & \secondlongthinexpression
\\
\newlabel{firstexpr} & \newlabel{secondexpr}
\end{array}
\]
.
.
.
In expressions~\eqref{firstexpr} and~\eqref{secondexpr}, we did blah blah blah.
```

Comment: Does it have to be in math mode? Since these or *graphical diagrams*, could you put them in a `figure` or even just a `tabular`, say?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think that changes the essence of the problem - I want a macro that generates new equation numbers associated to a particular label, and displays the number in-place. That's how I've set things up above. But if you see some better way to approach things given the context I've given, I'd be happy with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your own commands `\mylabel` (which works with the existing `equation` counter) and `\myref` command to typeset both the label and the reference. In the code below I used `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` to produce a face "thin equation", just for reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\newcommand*{\mylabel}[1]{% Label
  \refstepcounter{equation}% Correct increment for referencing and label
  \label{#1}% Label
  \textrm{(\theequation)}% Typeset label
}%
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\textrm{(\ref{#1})}}% Reference

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

\[
  \begin{array}{*{5}{c}}
    \rule{5pt}{4em} & \rule{5pt}{3em} & \rule{5pt}{4em} & \rule{5pt}{3em} & \rule{5pt}{4em} \\
    \mylabel{firstexpr} & \mylabel{secondexpr} & \mylabel{thirdexpr} & \mylabel{fourthexpr} & \mylabel{fifthexpr}
  \end{array}
\]

In expressions~\myref{firstexpr} and~\myref{secondexpr}, we did blah blah blah. However, in expressions~\myref{fifthexpr}, 
\myref{fourthexpr} and \myref{thirdexpr} we have blah blah blah blah. I really like~\myref{einstein}.

\end{document}​
```

[image: Thin equations with counter/label/reference]

Without any other specification, this works fine. However, if you use `amsmath`, a slight modification is required in the definitions of `\mylabel` and `\myref`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
...
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mylabel}[1]{% Label
  \refstepcounter{equation}% Correct increment for referencing and label
  \ltx@label{#1}% Label
  \textrm{(\@currentlabel{})}% Typeset label
}%
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\textrm{\eqref{#1}}}% Reference
```

Comment: Thanks Werner, that's delightful! But I will have other conventional equations in the document, so I really want to use the standard equation counter rather than a newly-declared one. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jamie: I've updated my answer to use the conventional `equation` counter of the document. It will even work if you change the formatting of the equation number to say `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}` for alphabetic equation numbers.

Comment: @Werner: your code won't work if the `amsmath` package is loaded; in this case, you'll need something like `\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mylabel}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{equation}
  (\@currentlabel{})
    \ltx@label{#1}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\eqref{#1}}`